# Index-Match with Sum-Function

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, array-formulas, google-query-language

I have two tabs `Product-Overview` and `Prices`.

On the `Prices`-tab I would like to add my data and get an overview on the financials tab.

[image]

I was trying to use `index-match`, however if there are several values in the same month in my `Prices`-tab I am not sure how to sum the up?

I would like to get the following result:

[image]

Find below my minimum viable example as google sheet:

[Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yVAoKbwojFwB39dISg0_YtvCF47jGPmn-2ycGdAEm5M/edit?usp=sharing)

Any suggestions how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

delete column D and use this in D2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="";;TEXT(B2:B; "mm/yy")))
```

[image]

then you can do this:

```
=QUERY(Prices!A2:D; "select A,sum(C) where A is not null group by A pivot D")
```

and more advanced in O5:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(O1:1="";;IF(B5:B="";;
 IFNA(VLOOKUP(B5:B; QUERY(Prices!A2:D; 
 "select A,sum(C) where A is not null group by A pivot D"); 
 MATCH(TO_TEXT(O1:T1); QUERY(QUERY(Prices!A2:D; 
 "select sum(C) where A is not null group by A pivot D"); 
 "limit 0"; 1); 0)+1; 0))*1)))
```

[image]

of course B5 can be:

```
=SORT(UNIQUE(Prices!A2:A))
```

[image]

then D5 can be:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B5:B="";;"Product "&REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(B5:B); ".(\d+)")))
```

[image]

average N5 can be done like:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(O5:100);
 "select "&TEXTJOIN(","; 1; IF(B5:B="";; 
 "avg(Col"&ROW(O5:O)-ROW(O5)+1&")"))&""));
 "select Col2"))
```

[image]

generating dates in O1 like:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(TEXT(ROW(INDIRECT(
 DATEVALUE("1/11/2020")&":"&
 DATEVALUE("1/11/2050"))); "mm/yy"))); 1; COLUMNS(O1:1)-1))
```

[image]

and years in O2 like:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(20&REGEXEXTRACT(O1:1; "/(\d+)")))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the `sumifs` formula:

This will solve your problem, it is not an arrayformula, but it works if you drag it for the cells you want them to go.

```
=sumifs(
  Prices!$C$2:$C;
  Prices!$A$2:$A;$B5;
  Prices!$D$2:$D;">="&if(isblank(N$1);date(year(O$1);month(O$1)-1;day(O$1));N$1);
  Prices!$D$2:$D;"<="&if(isblank(O$1);date(year(N$1);month(N$1)+1;day(N$1));O$1)
)
```

[image]